# HTTP health check - GET or HEAD and 200 or 204 response?

Tags: http, http-status-codes, health-monitoring, health-check

I’m wondering if there is a general convention for this: When implementing a HTTP health check for any given application where you are not interested in any response body but just the status code, what would the default/expected endpoint look like?

- Using a HEAD request - and returning 200 or 204 status code (which one of those?)
- Using a GET with 204
- something else?

Comment: you should read OPTIONS specification: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.7

Comment: From my point of view, a health check can be done with GET or HEAD, don't exists a general purpose convention. If i have to choose between GET or HEAD, i will choose HEAD because is faster and lighter for server and client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of my experience, people use mostly GET and 200. A health check wouldn't respond too much content, so no use of making a HEAD request. But this is mostly the case with a dedicated health check URL.

Today's cloud systems often use Kubernetes or OpenShift. They appear to use a `GET` request. I think they'll probably want to get a `200`ish response code, so `200-299`:

https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/dev_guide/application_health.html

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/

Another example, Drupal defines the HTTP response code to be `200`:

https://www.drupal.org/project/health_check_url

In Oracle's Infrastructure-as-a-Service docs you can choose between `GET` and `HEAD` requests, but the default is `HEAD`:

https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/healthchecks/20180501/HttpMonitor/

Answer (score 1):

Use a GET with 204 possibly supporting also HEAD with same status code

A [HEAD](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.2) should give the same response as GET but without response body, so you should first know/define what the GET response gives out in terms of headers (and status code), then, if you want, you can support also HEAD on the same endpoint, returning the same status, in this case 204.

Note that if `GET` `employee/34` anwswers with 404 also `HEAD` must anwser with same code. That means one must do the same work as for `GET`: check if employee esists, set status etc. but must not write any response. Tomcat supports this automatically as it uses for `HEAD` request a response object that never writes to the "real" response, so one can use same code handling `GET`

For a check one may consider also [TRACE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.8) but it produces a response body / output mirroring what you send to it, is different, I haven't seen implemented anywhere.

> TRACE allows the client to see what is being received at the other
> end of the request chain and use that data for testing or diagnostic
> information.

Comment: thanks, you explain well when to use GET vs HEAD. But can you also elude bit around the core of my question about what to use for health check endpoints?